# Why response is null from stored procedure when application is run from IIS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I make an ajax call to retrieve some data. I am using entity framework and ajax call leads to a stored procedure which successfully  returns me the data when I run application from visual studio.But it returns null data when I host my application in IIS.

Below is the ajax call :

```
 function GetChartData() {

    var FromDate = $('#FromDateFilter').val();
    var ToDate = $('#ToDateFilter').val();
    var EmailID = $('#hdnEmailID').val();
    var type = $('#hdnSentOrReceived').val();
    var url;

    if (type == 'sent') {
        url = '@Url.Action("getSentMailsCountPerDay", "Home")'
    }
    else {
        url = '@Url.Action("getReceivedMailsCountPerDay", "Home")'
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { EmailID: EmailID, FromDate: FromDate, ToDate: ToDate },
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        error: function (ex) {
            alert(ex.responseText);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data.issucess) {
                if (data.data.length) {
                    //alert('ssd');
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {

                        point = [data.data[i].TotalMails];
                        Points.push(point);

                        Day = [data.data[i].Day];
                        days.push(Day);
                    }
                    GenerateChart(Points, days);
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.error);
                    $("#canvas5").hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the controller code where I call entity framework stored procedure

```
 public ActionResult getSentMailsCountPerDay(string EmailID, string FromDate, string ToDate)
    {
        List<MailCountsPerDay> maildetailList = new List<MailCountsPerDay>();
        List<MailDetails> mailList = new List<MailDetails>();
        int cnt = 0;
        MailCountsPerDay existingMail = new MailCountsPerDay();
        try
        {
            BDEntities entities1 = new BDEntities();
            DateTime FilterByFromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime FilterByToDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ToDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var Result1 = entities1.spGetSentMailDetails(EmailID, FilterByFromDate, FilterByToDate);
            foreach (var item in Result1)
            {
                MailDetails mail = new MailDetails();
                mail.LogDateTime = TimeConverter(item.Timezone, Convert.ToDateTime(item.DateTime));

                MailCountsPerDay mails = new MailCountsPerDay();

                if (maildetailList.Where(x => x.DaTe.Contains(mail.LogDateTime.ToShortDateString())).Count() > 0)
                {
                    existingMail = maildetailList.Where(x => x.DaTe.Contains(mail.LogDateTime.ToShortDateString())).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                else
                {
                    cnt = 0;
                }

                mails.DaTe = mail.LogDateTime.ToShortDateString();

                mails.Day = mail.LogDateTime.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "-").Substring(0, mail.LogDateTime.ToShortDateString().LastIndexOf('-'));

                mails.TotalMails = ++cnt;

                if (mails.DaTe != null && cnt == 1)
                    maildetailList.Add(mails);
                else
                {
                    if (existingMail != null)
                        existingMail.TotalMails = mails.TotalMails;
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
        }

        return Json(new { issucess = true, data = maildetailList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Finally this is my SP in SQL :

```
select M.*,BD.Country,BD.Timezone from tblMailDetails M,tblBDMailID BD
where M.FromEmailId = @EmailID and 
BD.MailID = @EmailID and 
 M.ToEmailId Not LIKE '%@tatvasoft.com%' and  M.ToEmailId Not LIKE     '%@etatvasoft.com%' and
CAST(M.[DateTime] as DATE) >= CONVERT(date,  @FilterByFromDate) and     CAST(M.[DateTime] as DATE) <= CONVERT(date,  @FilterByToDate)
```

Please help if possible.

Comment: Hint: permissions......

Comment: put a return in the catch... which changes issucess to false... this will show you error then if there are any.. after you have done that, please confirm you get any errors. you need to modify your js to handle the errors also... so you can see it

Comment: @Seabizkit your comment helped me.Thanks a lot.